# как удалить зубчатость с границы перекошенного div

Tags: css

Как удалить зубчатость с границы перекошенного div?

```
-webkit-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg) ;
transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, если кто-либо ищет это позже,  чтобы избавиться от этих неровных краев при преобразованиях CSS в Chrome, заключается в добавлении свойства CSS 
    `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

```css
.skew {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew"></div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вовсе нет ни какого эффекта...

Answer (score 2):

Зависит всё от браузера, устройства и графической составляющей.

Если "лесенка", всё таки наблюдается в большинстве устройств, то придётся воспользоваться `filter: blur();`, ну и подбирать при каком значение меньше всего будет заметно "лесенку".

```js
$('input').bind('change', function(){
  
  $('.skew').css('filter','blur('+( $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0 )+'px)');
});
```

```css
.skew {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="skew"></div>
<input type="checkbox" checked> включить "сглаживание"
```

Comment: **P.s.** `filter: blur();` будет накладывать блюр и на дочерние элементы..